# Subtracting every single column of a dataframe with each other efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

for example I have a data frame depicted below and I would to create a new dataframe which has columns as the subtraction of  previous ones.

Dataframe given: (could have any number of columns)

```
  A    B    C
0  10  100  200
1  15  115  215
2  20  120  220
3  25  125  225
4  30  130  230


Dataframe required
   A-B  A-C  B-A  B-C  C-A  C-B
0  ..
1  ..
2  ..
3  ..
4
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Edit: Using itertools.permutations instead of itertools.combinations as pointed out by Austin Wagner's comment in order to determine all of the possible combinations in one command.

You need to determine all of the possible combinations, and calculate the subtraction result for each of them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [10, 15, 20, 25, 30],
    'B': [100, 115, 120, 125, 130],
    'C': [200, 215, 220, 225, 230]
})

def subtractions_of_combinations(df):
    # Extract all the combinations
    combinations = list(itertools.permutations(df.columns, 2)) 
    # Calculate the two possible subtractions for each combination
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for a, b in combinations:
        new_df[f'{a}-{b}'] = df[a] - df[b]
    return new_df
```

Comment: You might want to use itertools permutations instead if you want every possible combination.

Comment: No need to do the list comprehension in get col just `itertools.permutations(df.columns,2):`

Comment: Thank you so much.